# Cannot change the value --None-- from a custom picklist when I change the record type

Tags: lightning-web-components, community

I had an inconvenience, I follow the instructions for this kind of issue from different websites and also stack exchange, but I'm not able to display other values in the picklist it only displays --None--, IDK if is a bug because the changes are not being applied in classic nor lightning. this only happened when I tried to change the record type from the record

This is how is set up the custom picklist:
[image]

How the picklist is setup in record type A:

[image]

Record type B:

[image]

And the page layout:

[image]

but is not making any change in  Lightning Experience and classic:

[image]

[image]

can someone help me or explain to me how to fix it?

Comment: Can you check the correct record type that you have made the changes?

Comment: @AnkaiahBandi I checked in Record Type A and B both have a **new** as the default value, and still, not displaying new when I tried to update the record when I change the record type, only when I create a brand new record

Comment: Are you saying, --None-- value coming for existing records?

Comment: when you create new record, Are you still getting --None-- value or its for existing records?

Comment: @AnkaiahBandi, Yes I mean when I created the record the picklist shows the default value, but when I want to change the record type from A to B I want that picklist value already selected with  **New**, but when I try to edit the fields from record type A to B the picklist display **None** and no **New**

Comment: This is expected behavior. If you use record types, changing the default value of the master picklist doesn’t affect the default value of the picklist for a record type. Refer the  https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.updating_picklists.htm&type=5